# emacs shell tab file name completion never close and multiply - after gdb locking in windows fix

Tags: emacs, gdb, tab-completion

See further below for the original question.

I've used gdb for over a couple of decades, and after an update gdb started defeating c-x-b and preventing windows from being used to view things I wanted to see, while forcing bindings to buffers I didn't care to see.  The fix seems to have broken tab completion for shells.

Ah, so how can I to stop gdb from taking control of the buffers/windows/frames layout without breaking something else?

```
;; fix 'feature' of broken gdb where it takes control of an
;; emacs window, and locks the user out from switching from it
;;
  (defun set-window-undedicated-p (window flag)
    "Never set window dedicated."
     flag)
  (advice-add 'set-window-dedicated-p :override #'set-window-undedicated-p)
```

--- problem in the original post --->

about a year back, after an update, file name completion windows in the shell stopped closing after the completion.  I figured this behavior would go away on the next release .. but it never has.

[image: In the shell I have typed 'ls' and see three files in a directory, "ab", "ac", and "ad".]

hitting tab -- all good

[image: hitting tab -- all good]

after completion, then another ls with tab

[image: after completion, then another ls with tab]

I can repeat this process until my shell panel is all but crowded out, and emacs fills with completion panels that all contain additional views of the shell.

[image: e4]
[image: e5]
[image: e6]

Is this some kind of new feature that can be turned off? Or is it, as seems more likely, a bug?  (How can it have lived for so long!?). Is there a simple way without taking one's hands off the keyboard to, in general, close the completion window so that the screen looks like it did before hitting tab?

[I had to take out the more detailed descriptions of the images because with them, stack exchange complained of unformatted code and wouldn't take the post... there was not even a hint of code in them. Anyway, this should be good enough.]

Comment: Please confirm that you see the problem even when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file). (If you don't see it, then bisect your init file to find the culprit.)

Comment: Thanks drew.  One look at my .emacs file and suspicious code jumped out.  It is related to fix to stop gdb from locking windows into place.  I will mod the original question rather than expanding further here.